# How to convert rows into column separator with any combinations

Tags: sql

If i have a table with 2 column id and name :

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfo0O.png)

And i want to convert this table become below table

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBOax.png)

How to create the sql query? I try to use collect_set but i dont get the combinations. I got only 1 combinations

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my solution you not get all combination but only one combination you can get

```
select ID,
stuff((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(Name as varchar(10))
       FROM Person t2
       Where t1.ID = t2.ID
       FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') Name
from Person t1
group by ID
```